# Default constructor not found for type CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm trying to add [CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/) to my Xamarin.Forms project. I'm adding the control directly in XAML without any binding like this:

```
<cv:CarouselViewControl>
   <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
         <Label Text="Page 1"/>
         <Label Text="Page 2"/>
         <Label Text="Page 3"/>
      </x:Array>
   </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
</cv:CarouselViewControl>
```

I have also initialized the control in both the projects IOS and Android.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
LoadApplication(new App());
```

But while running the project, It's throwing this error at `LoadApplication(new App());`

```
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/blob/master/CarouselView/CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android/CarouselViewImplementation.cs/), it's clear that the renderer is having the only constructor with one parameter. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix the issue but I'm sure there is something I am missing.

#### Update

Here are the requested codes:

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;    
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Iconize;
using FormsPlugin.Iconize.Droid;
using CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android;

namespace One.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "One", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            IconControls.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar, Resource.Id.tabMode);
            CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
            var app = new App();
            app.TriggerFullScreenSwitch += (s) => { if (s) MakeFullScreen(); else ExitFullScreen(); };
            LoadApplication(app);
            MakeFullScreen();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes it the full screen.
        /// </summary>
        private void MakeFullScreen()
        {
            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
            int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Exits the full screen.
        /// </summary>
        private void ExitFullScreen()
        {
            Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:One"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             x:Class="One.Showcase" local:XamarinPage.ShowFullScreen="true">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <cv:CarouselViewControl>
                <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
                        <Button Text="Page 1"/>
                        <Label Text="Page 2"/>
                        <Label Text="Page 3"/>
                    </x:Array>
                </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
            </cv:CarouselViewControl>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace One
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Showcase : ContentPage
    {
        public Showcase ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the complete XAML + XAML.CS code, and the complete `MainActivity.cs` code? I'm unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick though there wasn't anything which had any issues, I have still added the complete code.

Comment: default constructor is always empty with no parameters, as It only has one constructor which requires one argument you are obviously not supplying the argument needed so it tries to construct the object with the default constructor which does not exist.

Comment: @furier I'm sorry but I think you didn't get the question. CarouselView is a 3rd party library. I don't get to call the constructor. It has the `Init()` method which I can call and that I have done. The constructor is called within the library itself to render the view.

Comment: XAML is just a different way to express the same thing you do in C#, maybe your XAML is missing something?

Comment: @furier I have copied the example from the git's readme. I did try initializing every property in that class in Xaml, but it didn't matter. I tried with different pages, it didn't work. I have (in)wasted whole day in figuring out the issue but was unable to. So I put it here. There is nothing on google either.

Comment: Looks like it may have been an issue with version 5.0.1. Just now got the update and version 5.0.2 is working without the issue. Thanks everyone for taking the pain with me.

Comment: Yeah I stand by my claim that what I said was the issue, however it was no your fault but the framework, they surely fixed the problem. :)

Comment: @AnupSharma , did you figure this out yet ? I am having the same problem and cannot find any answer .Thanks

Comment: I am just looking into this same thing :-D

Comment: @Pxaml It was an issue with that particular version. It went away as soon as I updated to the new release that came exactly the same day. Maybe you can downgrade and try with the version 5.0.2.

Comment: @AnupSharma , Martin Zikmund, you wont believe but today I opened the project and Default constructor not found for type CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer this error came back after it was working before. I havent done any change to this implementation  . how odd is this ?

Comment: @Pxaml Maybe you have updated the packages and you didn't notice it.

Comment: I'm getting this today. Anyone have a fix for this>